# How to turn the following "then" and use await/async instead (map function)?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

The following code takes a bunch of file paths, reads the files, then counts their words:

```
;(async () => 
  const wordCounts = await Promise.all(
    filePaths.map(
      filePath => fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8')
        .then(fileText => nlp(fileText).wordCount())
    )
  )
})()
```

How to use `async/await` instead of that `then` at the end?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `.map` callback async so you can `await` the call of `readFile`:

```
;(async () => {
  const wordCounts = await Promise.all(
    filePaths.map(async (filePath) => {
      const fileText = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8');
      return nlp(fileText).wordCount();
    })
  )
})()
```

Async functions, when called, return Promises which resolve to the value returned inside the async function, so having the callback be async is just fine, since it's being passed to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Thanks. Suddenly everything looks clearer with the brackets and the return.